Sentencepiece crashes during normalization of bigger files
I'm trying to train my own tokenizer with sentencepiece:
import sentencepiece as spm
import re
import os
import tempfile

input_file = "path/to/txtfile.txt"
vocab_size = 300 #increase this for bigger files

spm.SentencePieceTrainer.train(
    input=input_file,
    input_format="text",
    model_prefix='custom_tokenizer',
    vocab_size=vocab_size,
    character_coverage=0.9995,
    input_sentence_size=100000000, # 0 means no limit
    seed_sentencepiece_size=1000000, # for faster training
    shuffle_input_sentence=True,
    max_sentencepiece_length=8,
    max_sentence_length=16768,
    split_by_unicode_script = True,
    split_by_whitespace = True,
    split_by_number = True,
    split_digits=True,
    allow_whitespace_only_pieces=True,
    byte_fallback=True,
    normalization_rule_name="identity",
    add_dummy_prefix=True,
    remove_extra_whitespaces=False,
    train_extremely_large_corpus=False,
    unk_id = 0,
    bos_id = 1,
    eos_id = 2,
    pad_id = 3,
    unk_piece = "<unk>",
    bos_piece = "<s>",
    eos_piece = "</s>",
    pad_piece = "<pad>",
    model_type='bpe'  # You can choose 'unigram', 'bpe', 'char', etc.
)

When I try to feed in a bigger text file (I tried a 4Gb .txt file but I don't know the exact "limit"), it fails during the normalization step:
...
trainer_interface.cc(425) LOG(INFO) Adding meta_piece: <0xFA> 
trainer_interface.cc(425) LOG(INFO) Adding meta_piece: <0xFB> 
trainer_interface.cc(425) LOG(INFO) Adding meta_piece: <0xFC> 
trainer_interface.cc(425) LOG(INFO) Adding meta_piece: <0xFD> 
trainer_interface.cc(425) LOG(INFO) Adding meta_piece: <0xFE> 
trainer_interface.cc(425) LOG(INFO) Adding meta_piece: <0xFF> 
trainer_interface.cc(430) LOG(INFO) Normalizing sentences...

I also find this reported as a github issue but it was closed without a solution: https://github.com/google/sentencepiece/issues/770
